# how to read specific message body in android

Tags: android, parsing, sms

i want to read SMS with a specific content (e.g. messages that only contain #RED on it) 
i already managed to read SMS from a specific number 
can i just change something here, or i need to make another method?

```
 public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, "address='3636'", null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                    "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

if anyone can help it would be useful. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand question correctly, you can make simple method like this:

```
public boolean someMethod(String string){
    return yourSmsString.toLowerCase().contains(string.toLowerCase());
}
```

And in your code, you can use it:

```
if(someMethod(#RED)){
    //doSomething
}
```

and if you don't want to create new method do this:

```
    if (yourString.toLowerCase().contains("#RED".toLowerCase())){
        //doSomething
    }
```

Comment: do you have any ideas how to read the first line of the message and then separate them into different categories based on the content of the first line?

Comment: Maybe something like this: String[] tableOfLines = yourString.split("/n");
and then you have in tableOfLines[0] your first line and you can use method in the answer above.

Comment: if I read specific keyword would it be easier than reading the first line? the keyword is always on the first line

Comment: Well, you have to figure it out by yourself, I don't know how your code looks like, and what is the best way to handle it. If it works for you, you should implement it.

Comment: well, i could use a little help here:) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159243/split-sms-with-only-on-its-body-andriod)